# Shopify images are blurring

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, shopify

When I add images to a [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) site that I'm working on (Brooklyn theme) they appear blurry unless shrunk to a very small size. The images I'm working with are 1748 x 1240, 300dpi.

My goal is to add a JQuery image slider ([lightslider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/)) to the site and this is where I first discovered the issue: the thumbnails look fine (at 95 x 67) but the main carousel image is blurry (the image width is set to 100%, resulting in a max-width of 891 x 633 within its parent div).

I've tested the slider outside of [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) and the images don't appear blurry. I've also tried adding the images separately from the slider and tested a different slider ([flex-slider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html)) within the Shopify theme and in both of these cases the large images are blurry.

My only theory is there's something within the Shopify theme CSS that's affecting my images. Does anyone know if this would be the case or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be possible. Two things come to mind:

1. Are the images really 1748 x 1240? If you right click on the blurry image and select "view image" what are the dimensions of the image?
2. If your css width is 100% is your css height:auto?

Also I haven't seen this in ages but it might be worth trying a different browser. In the past some browsers had horrible scaling engines for images. You might try manually scaling the images so they are only 891 x 633 -- if that is their actual max then downloading the larger ones is a waste of bandwidth anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bknights. After a bit more research I've discovered that Shopify is actually automatically resizing the images. I'm looking into this further myself but if anyone has experienced this before I'd be very grateful for advice!